# How to grep all following text using regular expression?

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to grep the text start from:

```
NSLocalizedStringFile(@"
```

and endWith

```
")
```

and I use this to grep:

```
(NSLocalizedStringFile\(@")()|(\);)
```

but it seems that my regular expression doesn't work, wt did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is the input to be grep'ed on one line or on multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command seems to do it.  I use the -P (perl-style regexp) flag to grep to make it easier to search for a multi-line string, since I wasn't sure if the start & end strings were expected to appear on the same line.

```
grep -P '(NSLocalizedStringFile\(@")[\s\S]*?"\)' foo.txt
```

Here's the contents of my test file:

```
this should not be included
NSLocalizedStringFile(@"
this should be included
")
this should not be included
```

Note that (as is typical of regexps), this won't do any matching of ('s with )'s.